# What does $f\in L^p(\partial \Omega )$ mean

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Let $\Omega $ a bounded smooth surface with boundary of $\mathbb R^n$. What does $$f|_{\partial \Omega }\in L^p(\partial \Omega )\ \ ?$$
Is it $$\int_{\partial \Omega }|f|_{\partial \Omega }|^p<\infty 
 \ \ ?$$
To be honnest, I don't really understand the meaning of $$\int_{\partial \Omega }|f|_{\partial \Omega }|^p,$$
because $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ and here we integrate on "$n-1$" value.

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lp-Space.html

Comment: @Winther: I know what are $L^p$ space, it's not my question. Sorry for the typo, I corrected it :)

Comment: Yes that is the definition of being in $L^p$. That the integral exists

Comment: what mean $\int_{\partial \Omega }|f|_\Omega |^p$ ? Because $\partial \Omega $ has measure $0$, so $f|_{\partial \Omega }$ could be anything (and in particular $0$)... Moreover, $f$ has $n$ variable, si $\int_{\partial \Omega }f$ looks strange since $\partial \Omega $ has dimension $n-1$...

Comment: @Winther: If $f\in {L^1}(\mathbb R^2)$ then on a set of measure $0$ the function $f$ is not well defined (it can be everything). Indeed, let $g=0$ in $\partial \Omega $ and $g=f$ in $\mathbb R^2\backslash \partial \Omega $, then $f=g$ in $L^2$, and thus $\int_{\partial \Omega }f=\int_{\partial \Omega }g=0$.

Comment: @Winther: Henri is correct, a function in $L^p$ is defined almost every only (it may no sense to specify the values of a function on a set of measure $0$). But here $f|_{\partial \Omega }$ is the trace of $f$ and is defined as a limit (see my answer).

Comment: @Surb Ah my bad, I did not see the tag. I read this as a PDE question where $f|_{\partial \Omega}$ is the boundary condition.

Answer (score 1):

Here thing are different. Do you know [trace operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator)  ? $\mathcal C^0(\bar \Omega )$ is dense in $L^p(\Omega )$. Let $(f_n)$ a sequence of $\mathcal C^0(\bar \Omega )$ functions that converge to $f$ in $L^p$. Then, by definition $$f|_{\partial \Omega }=\lim_{n\to \infty }f_n|_{\partial \Omega },$$
in $L^p(\partial \Omega )$ sense, that mean $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{\partial \Omega }|f-f_n|=0.$$ For your second question, notice that $\partial \Omega $ is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, and thus $\int_{\partial \Omega }f|_{\partial \Omega }$ make sense.

Comment: The set of continuous functions with compact support is also dense in $L^p(\Omega)$. That definition would imply that $f|_{\partial\Omega}=0$ for all $f\in L^p$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre: Thank you for your comment, rigorously you are totally right. I just wanted to give a motivation on how to define $f|_{\partial \Omega }$  (or an illustration on how it could work). Indeed, it's a little more subtly and require Sobolev spaces to define the trace properly (because $\mathcal C^1(\bar \Omega )$ is dense in $W^{1,p}(\Omega )$ whereas $\mathcal C^{1}(\Omega )$ with compact support is not).